# How to turn on or off "Location Service Checking" for particular application in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, cllocationmanager

Just like `Location Service Enabling` or `GPS Enabling` in iOS, how could I also enable `Location Service Enabling` for running application? And also `Background Refresh Service` in iOS. Here is the code, using i enable `Location Service`.
What happen here, is : if my `Location Service` is off, then it show a alertView and if i click `settings` button it takes me to the settings>>privacy>>Location Service page.

Code:

```
CLLocationManager *locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
locationManager.delegate = self;
[locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
```

Is there any thing handy like the above code?

Comment: I don't get you. you want something like `locationManager: didUpdateToLocation: fromLocation:`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't fully understand your question, but I think you're asking how you can show an alert to the user with a button that, when pressed, takes the user to Settings > Privacy > Location Services.

Unfortunately that's out of your control. If Location Services is off, the system will prompt the user once to go to Settings and turn it on. If the user taps "Cancel" they won't see that alert again. The systems seems to take the stance that it will bug the user as little as possible. If they've been asked, they won't be asked again.

There's no way to fire your own alert with a button that takes the user to Settings. The best you can do is fire an alert that explains what they need to do in order for your app to utilize their location.